# Translate Scheme closure-defining function into Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, types, scheme, closures

The following procedure, written in Scheme,

```lisp
(define (eat xs)
  (lambda (x)
    (if (eq? x 'vomit)
      (reverse xs)
      (eat (cons x xs)))))
```

can be called in the following way:

```lisp
> eat 
#{procedure 9165 eat}
> (eat '())
#{procedure 9166 (unnamed in eat)}
> ((eat '()) 1)
#{procedure 9166 (unnamed in eat)}
> (((((eat '()) 1) 2) 3) 4)
#{procedure 9166 (unnamed in eat)}
> ((((((eat '()) 1) 2) 3) 4) 'vomit)
(1 2 3 4)
```

As there is no mutation eg. `set!`, and the state is passed using recursion I thought this would be trivial to write in Haskell:

```hs
eat xs x = if x == "vomit" then reverse xs else eat (x:xs)

-- Couldn't match expected type ‘[[Char]]’
--        with actual type ‘[Char] -> [[Char]]’
-- Probable cause: ‘eat’ is applied to too few arguments
-- In the expression: eat (x : xs)
-- In the expression:
--   if x == "vomit" then reverse xs else eat (x : xs)
```

Am I missing something glaringly obvious, or is it just not possible?

Comment: What would the type of the `eat` function be?

Comment: maybe something like `eat :: [a] -> a -> Eat a`

Comment: or `eat :: [a] -> a -> Either [a] (a -> Either [a] (a -> Either ...`

Comment: It's "impossible" because you're playing too fast and loose with the types in this function. Passing the result `'vomit` yields a list, but passing anything else yields a procedure. Haskell is statically typed, so you can't get away with the same sort of thing. You could make it return an `Either` type, but that's the best you'll get.

Comment: There are some tricks to simulate varargs functions in Haskell, like those used by Haskell's `printf`, but they involve some deep type class hackery.

Comment: @chi this is not a varargs function in Scheme. What it does, is building a new closure (a function) and returning it, when given a non-"vomit" argument.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you have a recursive type in there, you need to declare it explicitly:

```hs
data T a = L [a] | F (a -> T a)

(+>) (F f) = f
unL  (L x) = x

eat xs x = if x == "vomit" then L $ reverse xs else F $ eat (x:xs)

eaten = unL $ eat [] "x" +> "y" +> "z" +> "vomit"
```

> *> eaten 
>
>       ["x","y","z"]*

Defining

```hs
eaten1 = eat [] "x" +> "y" 

eaten2 = eaten1 +> "z" +> "vomit"
```

also works:

> *> unL $ eaten1 +> "vomit"
>
>     ["x","y"]* 
>   *> unL $ eaten2 
>
>      ["x","y","z"]*

Comment: completely forgot about the need for defining a recursive type

Comment: Haskell handles recursive types for us, without us having to know how it is achieving that. But we need to declare a specific type for that, for with general type variables it is forbidden: `[a] ~ a -> [a]` is invalid because `a` stands for *any* type; but when we declare `T`, it, specifically, can be recursive.